# FFmpeg - Vertical-Scroll Image Overlay for same duration as audio file

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to scroll an image vertically, but I want the animation duration to match an mp3 file, which will be different every time. Here's what I have:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=s=1280x720 -loop 1 -i "image.jpg" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1280:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.01/TB),fps=30[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.01':eof_action=endall[video]" -map "[video]" "output.mp4"
```

But this always produces a video with duration of 1 minute and 40 seconds, making the animation slow down or speed up accordingly. This is not what I want. I want the output video (and the scrolling animation) duration to match a random mp3 file.

I am using FFmpeg in a Batch file on Windows. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted by doing this:

```
set "CommandLine=ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a:0 -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0 audio.mp3"
for /F "delims=" %%b in ('!CommandLine!') do set /a duration=%%b
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -vf "crop=1280:720:0:'t*(ih-oh)/!duration!'" -t !duration! output.mp4
```